Invalid Value when using the subscriptionv2 api
The Purchase token i used for testing is like : GPA.3376-9095-7476-99xxx
I'm not sure if it a purchase token as i use adapty and this is the transaction ID i got from it.
def check_android_subscription(purchase_token, logger):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        settings.GOOGLE_API_CREDENTIALS
    )

    response = (
        googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            "androidpublisher", "v3", credentials=credentials
        )
        .purchases()
        .subscriptionsv2()
        .get(packageName="com.comapny.app", token=purchase_token)
        .execute()
    )

    logger(f"Response: {response}", level="INFO")

    subscription_state = response.get('subscriptionState', SUBSCRIPTION_STATE_UNSPECIFIED)
    is_pro = subscription_state in [SUBSCRIPTION_STATE_ACTIVE, SUBSCRIPTION_STATE_IN_GRACE_PERIOD]

    ProUserProfile.objects.update_or_create(
        id=purchase_token,
        defaults={'is_pro': is_pro}
    )

    return is_pro

when i run the above code i'm getting
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.comapny.app/purchases/subscriptionsv2/tokens/GPA.3376-9095-7476-99xxx?alt=json returned "Invalid Value". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid Value', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid'}]">

I want to know what is causing this issue and how to solve this
